# Why spark is reading more data that I expect it to read using read schema?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, parquet, delta-lake

In my spark job, I'm reading a huge table (parquet) with more than 30 columns. To limit the size of data read I specify schema with one column only (I need only this one). Unfortunately, when reading the info in spark UI I get the information that the `size of files read` equals 1123.8 GiB but `filesystem read data size total` equals 417.0 GiB. I was expecting that if I take one from 30 columns the `filesystem read data size total` will be around 1/30 of the initial size, not almost half.

Could you explain to me why is that happening?

Comment: You could try using `LIMIT n,m` where n and m are integers giving the first and last lines to read.

Comment: I want to fetch all rows, but not all columns.

Comment: I understand but if you have problem of capacity try fetching it in several batches, for example by 10000 rows `LIMIT 10000`, `LIMIT 10001,20000` etc

Comment: I don't have problem with that. I'm able to fetch eveyrthing but I'm wondering why it fetches so much.

Comment: The databases motor still has to read all the indexes etc. even if it only returns one column. If you wanted everything I would expect that there would be more read than the size of the whole table.